# Comparable compareTo to allow nulls like Comparator nullsFirst or nullsLast

Tags: java

There are countless questions and answers on `Comparable` and `Comparator` but none seem to address this question.

Say I have this method `compare` which takes any `Comparable` implementation of a and b and returns the comparison -1, 0, or 1.

```java
static <U,T extends Comparable<U>> int compare(T a, U b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

Works with any `Comparable` all is fine and dandy. Method is adopted by every project across the enterprise.

```
jshell> compare(1, 2);
$1 ==> -1

jshell> compare("id", "hi");
$2 ==> 1
```

Then out of the blue the data changes and we start having problems.

```
jshell> compare(null, "hi");
|  Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(Object)" because "<parameter1>" is null
|        at compare (#1:2)
|        at (#2:1)

jshell> compare(1, null);
|  Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "value" because "anotherInteger" is null
|        at Integer.compareTo (Integer.java:1473)
|        at Integer.compareTo (Integer.java:71)
|        at compare (#1:2)
|        at (#3:1)
```

Looking for answers on the other SO questions they will all repeat what [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) says:

> Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.

Now that is simply not acceptable! We have the [Comparator class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with methods like `nullsFirst` and `nullsLast` so how do we fix this problem, without changing the method name and signature. We want nulls to be less than non-nulls and when both are null, they should be considered equal. Also the client is very particular and will not be entertaining any if equals null or `if (a == null)` comparisons mucking about.

How do we change our popular compare method to still accept any two `Comparable`s including nulls and produce the following returns.

```
jshell> compare(1, 2);
$5 ==> -1

jshell> compare("id", "hi");
$6 ==> 1

jshell> compare(null, "hi");
$7 ==> -1

jshell> compare(1, null);
$8 ==> 1

jshell> compare(null, null);
$9 ==> 0
```

Comment: "Also the client is very particular and will not be entertaining any if equals null comparisons mucking about" What does this sentence mean?

Comment: If "that is simply not acceptable!" consider using another language.

Comment: @tgdavies no if equals null or `if (a == null)` comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the actual solution**: to change an existing compare method which takes two `Comparables` implementing `compareTo`, to also allow for null comparison like `Comparator.nullsFirst` does, without changing the name or signature of the method, and without using any if statements. Simple? =)

Current method:

```java
static <U,T extends Comparable<U>> int compare(T a, U b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

Becomes:

```java
static <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T a, T b) {
    return Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.<T>naturalOrder()).compare(a, b);
}
```

Since for `T extends Comparable<U>` we have `U extends T` which makes `U instanceof T`, so we can substitute `U` for `T` and the method signature remains unchanged.

There was never any need for null comparisons or reinventing a perfectly good wheel. Java can do what you want, most certainly it can, you must just be willing to put in the work.

nJoy

Comment: Of course the `compare` method that the code above uses runs lines such as `if (a == null) {return (b == null) ? 0 : (nullFirst ? -1 : 1); } else if (b == null) {...` but hopefully your client will not notice that!

Comment: @tgdavies the fact it creates new instance of comparator for every comparison is even worse, by the way, let client to pay aws bills such requirements :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to modify your `compare` method.  Change this:

```
static <U,T extends Comparable<U>> int compare(T a, U b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

to this:

```
static <U,T extends Comparable<U>> int compare(T a, U b) {
    if (a == null) {
        return (b == null) ? 0 : -1;
    } else if (b == null) {
        return +1;
    } else {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

---

> Client specifically doesn't want any if equals null or if (a == null) comparisons. Why can't we simply use `Comparator.nullsFirst` as it already does what we want?

Because it doesn't work.

(Correction: actually it would as [@AndreyB.Panfilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426309) commented on a now deleted answer:

```
return Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.<T>naturalOrder()).compare(a, b);
```

But that doesn't invalidate what I am about the say next.)

Sometimes client requirements are just so stupid that you have to push back.  You need to educate the client.  Seriously.  It is in *their best interests* to try.

But if you really have a client who insists beyond all reason that `null` literals are *The Spawn of Satan* (or something) ... you could implement the `null` check using `Objects.isNull` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-)).

Comment: Client specifically doesn't want any if equals null or `if (a == null)` comparisons. Why can't we simply use `Comparator.nullsFirst` as it already does what we want?

Comment: Why on earth would they specify that?

Comment: You know how the saying goes: "Client is always right" =)

Comment: "I heard that `null` was a billion dollar mistake, so we are banning `null` literals from our code!"

Comment: The best service you could provide to this client is to find out their reasoning and explain to them what their misunderstanding is.

Comment: If the client is willing to pay why wouldn't you put in the extra effort? The requirements were clear, has this become a norm now that developers either don't read the requirements or choose whether it suits them to implement and rather start an argument in refusal instead of completing the task? ...no wonder software is in such a state!

Comment: We even have the `Comparator.nullsFirst` solution but it too is incomplete, as the requirement states: "without changing the method name and signature"

Comment: The client is paying you to do the right thing, not pander to their misunderstandings.